# How can I subtract the same array from all the columns of a matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

How can I subtract the same array from all the columns of a matrix ? I can't use for cycles.

For example I have `w=([3,2],[4,3]`) and `v=(1,1)` and I want `w-v=([2,1],[3,2])`

Answer (score 1):

Are you working in `numpy`?

It's as simple as

```
w = np.array([[3,2], [4,3]])
v = np.array([1,1])
result = w-v
```

This is a useful skill for `numpy` called [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator expression like this:

```
tuple([a - b for a, b in zip(r, v)] for r in w)
```

This returns:

```
([2, 1], [3, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate and update the values of list w

```
for idx,tup in enumerate(zip(w,v)):
    for inner_idx,k in enumerate(tup[0]):
        w[idx][inner_idx]=k-tup[1]

print(w)#([2, 1], [3, 2])
```